# Multiple Input names and values into a single Input with Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with multiple text inputs and I want to take the name and value of each text input then display it.

So for example my code would look something like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="value1" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="value2" />
    <input type="text" name="input3" value="value3" />
    <input type="button" name="showResults" />
</form>
```

Then display it like this:

```
input1 = value1, input2 = value2, input3 = value3
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Etm8K/

API:

- http://api.jquery.com/html/
- http://api.jquery.com/each/

hope rest fits your need. `:)`

**Code**

```
$("#myForm").find(":input[type=text]").each(function () {
    // The selector will match buttons; if you want to filter
    // them out, check `this.tagName` and `this.type`; see
    // below
    $('#display').html($('#display').html() + this.name +  '=' + 
    $(this).val() + ',');
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that does exactly what I need it to do. Was trying for ages but never knew about the find() operator or switch or whatever it's called (jquery isn't my strong suit). How would I go about avoiding text inputs that are empty? Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to quickly edit my response and sneak another question in, but failed.. Sorry! How would I go about avoiding text inputs that are empty? Thanks again.

Comment: @user3818607 you can put a check inside `.each` for `if (this.value != '')` like this **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qdgMh/

Comment: Nevermind, worked it out - just added and IF check before the display.

Comment: Haha beat me again! Thanks :)